# Как вызвать метод из дочернего компонента Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вызвать метод из дочернего компонента

Родительский компонент

```
<template>
    <div>
       <base-modal-component></base-modal-component>
    </div>
</template>

export default {
        data() {
            return{}
        }

        methods: {
            updateForm(){
                console.log('Форма обновилась')
            }
        }
}
```

И дочерний компонент

```
<template>
    <div>
       <button @click="test">Обновить форму</button>
    </div>
</template>

export default {
        data() {
            return{}
        }

        methods: {
            test(){
                //тут нужно вызвать метод updateForm у родительского компонента
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передать как параметр дочернему компоненту. Всё это есть в документации.
`<base-modal-component v-bind:btnClickHandler="updateForm"></base-modal-component>`

```
methods: {
 test(){
  this.btnClickHandler();       
 }
}
```